# Extract thoughput value from JMeter log file

Tags: shell, awk

I use JMeter for load testing and want to report error on CI pipeline when application though put is less than 1/sec. JMeter logs summary of results as -

```
2017/01/17 01:57:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary +    103 in 00:00:30 =    3.4/s Avg:  2937 Min:    48 Max:  7962 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 10 Finished: 8 
2017/01/17 01:57:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =  12218 in 01:00:03 =    3.4/s Avg:  2942 Min:    20 Max: 27317 Err:     1 (0.01%)
2017/01/17 01:57:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary +      1 in 00:00:00 =   66.7/s Avg:  3227 Min:  3227 Max:  3227 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 10 Finished: 10 
2017/01/17 01:57:00 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =  12219 in 01:00:03 =    3.4/s Avg:  2942 Min:    20 Max: 27317 Err:     1 (0.01%)
```

Herein I would capture the last line and if value of throughput is less than 1 (which is 3.4/s in the current example) then it would be reported as error. Here is the script I wrote to capture value of throughput -

```
grep "meter.reporters.Summariser: summary" test.log | tail -1 | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d "." -f1
```

and it gets me 3 which is ok. How can I improve this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using here four different tools: `grep`, `tail`, `awk` and `cut` to do the following:

- select lines
- get the last one
- print a given field of that one
- extract the integer part of that field

This is clear and it works. However, using four processes is a bit of overkill, since all of these can be performed one-handedly via `awk`:

```
awk '/meter.reporters.Summariser: summary/ {rec=$12} END{printf "%d\n", rec}' file
```

- `/meter.reporters.Summariser: summary/ {rec=$12}`
  When reading from the file, `/pattern/` will match those lines containing the "pattern". If this happens, the action within `{}` is performed. In this case, it consists in storing the 12<sup>th</sup> field.
  But wait, weren't we looking for the last line in which this occurs? Yes, and this is exactly what we are doing by overwriting `rec` every time the pattern happens: last time it is written, it will store the definitive result.
- `END{printf "%d\n", rec}`
  Once all lines have been processed, `red` will have the desired value on the form `3.4/s`. We just want the `3` to appear, so we could do some string triming similar to the one you did with `cut`. However, we can also use `awk`'s [`printf()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters) to use Format-Control Letters to just print the integer part of it. This will also print `0` if `rec` is empty:

  ```
  $ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\n", "3.4/s"}'
  3.4/s
  $ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%d\n", "3.4/s"}'
  3
  $ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%d\n", ""}'
  0
  ```

Of course, you could also add the threshold logic in the script.